# Kotlin on android: Cannot find main merged manifest. What is causing this error?

Tags: android, kotlin

I wanted to give Kotlin a shot. I converted my java classes to Kotlin and corrected some errors. If I try to build, the following error comes up:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo'. Cannot find main merged manifest.

This is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mdrueke.kniffel">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Setup_Activity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you apply the Kotlin plugin correctly?

Comment: I configured Kotlin with gradle and added the Kotlin plugin and std lib in the gradle file.

Comment: Did you use the `kotlin-android` plugin and version `1.1.2-4`? Have you tried a clean rebuild?

Comment: Clean rebuild did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This also happens when just using java, and clean also solves it.

Answer (score 30):

I’ve been experimenting with Kotlin development in the just-released Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1 and get the “Cannot find merged manifest” error every now and again. I’ve found that selecting **Build -> Clean Project** solves the problem for me.

Comment: Works well. A summary of the other answers that work for some as well: Try editing the manifest file (add or remove whitespace), and if it still doesn't work try closing and opening Android Studio. After that, submit a bug report and make sure you don't have any errors in your project.

Answer (score 12):

**Clean Project** is worked for me in Android Studio 3.0 canary version

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I'm using Android studio 3.0 Canary 2, first i try **Build -> Clean Project** still not solves the problem for me, then I close the project and open it again, Alhamdulillah it's solves the problem

Comment: In my case it's not working. I'm using Canary 2 Build.

Answer (score 4):

I tried both cleaning the project and close-opening it, but they don't work in my case.
After editing the manifest (not a functional change) now project runs.

Comment: It's incredible, now the project is working! I changed only whitespaces and everything works fine. This answer should be accepted, cause it involves every possible fix.

Comment: Same here. Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3, doing any change in manifest (adding empty line, reformatting etc.) fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Because **Build -> Clean Project**, restarting Android Studio or reinstalling app may not work, the simplest solution was to change AndroidManifest.xml, e.g. add or delete white space.

Here is reported issue:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62336754.

As mentioned there, it will be fixed in `Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0-alpha5`.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by uninstalling the app you're currently working on and running it again on Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Tried the given solutions but wasn't successful. So for the mean time until this bug gets fixed I am going for the commandline

```
./gradlew clean install<your_build_variant>
```

Example:

```
./gradlew clean installDevDebug
```

Comment: Only your answer is working for me, but only I if run from command line. Apk is installed but if I want after that run in traditional way, I'm still getting 'Can't find main merged manifest' error. Have you resolved this?

Comment: @ThirdMartian Unfortunately no. Still stuck with the command line.

Comment: Did you report a bug on issue tracker? Android Gradle Plugin or Kotlin?